# Problema com uma lista de itens selecionáveis que são armazenados em um array

Tags: array, typescript, react-native, mobile

Olá, preciso criar uma lista em que eu possa selecionar um dos itens e também desselecionar, mas estou com problemas pois a lista só seleciona corretamente se eu selecionar em **ordem crescente e desselecionar em ordem decrescente** e não estou entendendo aonde esta o meu erro. Eu preciso que esta lista seja selecionavel/desselecionavel em qualquer ordem.

**PRINT DA LISTA**

[image: Print da lista, O problema é que só consigo selecionar ela em ordem crescente e decrescente, e preciso poder selecionar em qualquer ordem.]

**CÓDIGO DA LISTA**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
  Image,
} from "react-native";

import {
  widthPercentageToDP as wp,
  heightPercentageToDP as hp,
} from "react-native-responsive-screen";

const LISTA = [
  {
    id:1,
    title: "Teste",
  },
  {
    id:2,
    title: "Teste2",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Teste3",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "Teste 4",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: "123",
  },
];

const Item = ({ item, onPress, style }) => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={[estiloLista.objetoLista, style]}>
    <Text style={{ color: "white", fontSize: 20 }}>ID :{item.id}</Text>
    <Text style={{ color: "black", fontSize: 20 }}>Titulo: {item.title}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);

const Lista = () => {
  const [idSelecionado, setIdSelecionado] = useState([0]);

  function adicionarItem(id: number) {
    if (idSelecionado.indexOf(id) === -1) {
      setIdSelecionado([...idSelecionado, id]);
      idSelecionado.sort();
      console.log("nova coleção é: " + idSelecionado);
    } else if (idSelecionado.indexOf(id) > -1) {
      idSelecionado.sort();
      idSelecionado.splice(idSelecionado.indexOf(id), 1); 
      setIdSelecionado([...idSelecionado]);
      console.log("id removido: ", id);
      console.log("nova coleção, apos removido é: ", idSelecionado);
    }
  }

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    const backgroundColor =
      item.id === idSelecionado[item.id] ? "lightsteelblue" : "red";
    const icone =
      item.id === idSelecionado[item.id]
        ? require("../src/assets/icones/basic/check_bold.png")
        : null;

    return (
      <View
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
        }}
      >
        <Item
          item={item}
          onPress={() => adicionarItem(item.id)}
          style={{ backgroundColor }}
        />

        <Image
          source={icone}
          style={{ position: "relative", top: "-50%", left: "-40%" }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <FlatList
        data={LISTA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        extraData={idSelecionado}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
export default Lista;

const estiloLista = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  textoLista: {
    fontSize: 24,
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  objetoLista: {
    width: wp("95%"),
    height: wp("15%"),
    backgroundColor: "lightsteelblue",
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: "grey",
    margin: 10,
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

**OBRIGADO A TODOS**

Answer (score 1):

Para facilitar sua lógica, na sua lista adiciona um atributo `selected` dessa forma:

```
const LISTA = [
  {
    id:1,
    title: "Teste",
    selected: false,
  },
  {
    id:2,
    title: "Teste2",
    selected: false,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Teste3",
    selected: false,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "Teste 4",
    selected: false,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: "123",
    selected: false,
  },
];
```

Essa variável vai controlar se o item da lista está selecionado ou não, você irá usar ele para sua lógica de cores e ícone, dessa forma:

```
const backgroundColor = item.selected ? "lightsteelblue" : "red";
```

Agora para alterar quando o item está selecionado ou não você vai precisar percorrer a lista, encontrar o respectivo item e alterar o atributo `selected`. Uma forma de fazer isso pode ser assim:

```
function alteraItem(id: number) {
    LISTA.forEach((elemento) => {
        if(elemento.id === id) {
            if(elemento.selected){
                elemento.selected = false
            } else {
                elemento.selected = true
            }
        }
    })
    console.log("nova coleção é: " + LISTA);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Use react states e crie state para ver se o item está selecionado ou não, mais ou menos assim.**

// create your list with state true or false

```
const generateFilterWithState = (original, selected = []) => original.map(value => ({
  value,
  filterState: selected.includes(value)
}));

handleSelectAll (item) {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
          itens: {
            ...prevState.itens,
            [item]: prevState.itens[item].map(
              ({ value, filterState }) => ({
                value,
                filterState: true
              })
            )
          }
        }));

  handleClearAll (item) {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      itens: {
        ...prevState.itens,
        [item]: prevState.itens[item].map(
          ({ value, filterState }) => ({
            value,
            filterState: false
          })
        )
      }
    }));
  }
```

Comment: Olá, aqui é o stackoverflow **em português**. Clique em [edit] e atualize sua resposta.